# Use a single column to index/match in two columns

Tags: regex, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-formula, textjoin

I want to use a single column to do a lookup in two columns.  Example below.

```
| a |   | c | a | foo |   | c | a | foo |
| b |   | e | c | bar |   | b | a | baz |
| c |   | b | a | baz |
| d |
```

The first table is the data I'm using to match on.

The second table is the data table that I'm indexing into.

The third table is the result I want.

Comment: Where do you run into trouble?  Please post the formula you have tried

Comment: It's pretty unclear what you want.  How do you get from a single column with four entries to three columns with two entries?

Comment: Please share a sample sheet illustrating the problem.  The tabular data you shared is not enough to answer the question.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook There are 2 input tables (1x4, 3x3) with 1 output table (3x2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=FILTER(C:E, 
 REGEXMATCH(C:C&"", "^"&TEXTJOIN("$|^", 1, A:A)&"$"), 
 REGEXMATCH(D:D&"", "^"&TEXTJOIN("$|^", 1, A:A)&"$"))
```

[image: 0]

note, it's case sensitive